# Show images without spacing in a gridview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gridview

I want to show images in a two column grid without vertical or horizontal spacing.The images are loaded using Picasso library. This is my code. In most cases it works fine. But in some devices in landscape mode there are spacing between images. How to correct it.

GridView:

```
<GridView 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
android:numColumns="2"
android:id="@+id/movie_grid_view"
/>
```

image_layout.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/movie_poster"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In the cursor adapter:

```
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.image_layout, parent, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    ImageView v= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.movie_poster);
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(cursor.getString(col_img)).into(v);
}
```

In landscape mood there are spaces between images

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting: `imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);` ?

Comment: better to add preview of ur `gridview`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this in your **image_layout.xml**

**android:scaleType="fitXY"** to scale the image

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/movie_poster"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
</LinearLayout>
```

hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the android margin to 0. Like this:

```
android:margin="0"
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve spacing problem try this Gridview.

**GridView:**

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/MyGrid" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="2dp" 
    android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
    android:scrollingCache="true" 
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    android:clipChildren="true" 
    android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="true"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit" 
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#000000">
</GridView>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: No. It doesn't give the result I want.